# CSS positioning and sizing behaviour

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn a little CSS and am about to give up at positioning and sizing the elements.

Why does

```
#name {

height: 25% ;
}
```

cause the `div` to keep the size that is needed by it's content (like, if there is only one line of text, the `div` will be just one line in height).

But as soon as i add `position: relative ;` it will be 25% high?

That seems to mean that i have to add the position attribute everytime i want an element to change it's size, even if i don't want to take it's position out of the static flow.

Also i do not understand which unit i should pick for my sizing. em, px, percentage...it's kinda overkill. I thought it will be useful to use % everytime in order to keep the layout "dynamic" or "responsive", is this false?

One last thing: Why do most designers use the `class`-attribute instead of `id`, which is nearly unused as far as i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different elements have different default `display` values applied to them for example: a `div` has a default `display` of `block` whereas `span` elements use `inline`, you are probably trying to adjust the height of an `inline` element.

As for measurements, they all have their place however I usually try and stick to `em` as then the sizes will adjust with the font size. Percentages are useful in certain situations as are px. However as far as responsive design is concerned you should be primarily using media queries (although using percentage measurements can also aid on this front).

To answer your final question, ids can only be used once in the html and thus can only apply to one element, classes can be used multiple times for many elements so it only makes sense that there are going to be more declarations of them in the html.

Comment: Adding to this: You want to use ID´s to target certain elements. You can use different classes on one element - if you need to. `<div class="button-big button-red text-white">...</div>` for example to get a big red button with white text.